# How to call AppService in WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

When i call AppService on UWP app, the AppServiceConnectionStatus returns Success. But, when i call AppService on winform  client, the AppServiceConnectionStatus still return AppServiceUnavailable. UWP,Winform the client code are the same，The following is the same code in uwp and WinForm:

```
var appService = new AppServiceConnection();

        // Here, we use the app service name defined in the app service provider's Package.appxmanifest file in the <Extension> section.
        appService.AppServiceName = "com.yanscorp.appservicedemo.Values";

        // Use Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id.FamilyName within the app service provider to get this value.
        appService.PackageFamilyName = "c97887ad-1f75-4b48-9e3b-21b89c061715_6evysfdvxt248";

        //uwp return Success,but winform return AppServiceUnavailable
        var status = await appService.OpenAsync();
        if (status != AppServiceConnectionStatus.Success)
        {
            textBlock.Text = "Failed to connect";
            return;
        }
```

Comment: I can successfully consume an AppService from Winform app, if I start the app by double click. However, if I debug the app from VS, it did failed to connect to the service (status is *Unknown*). This leads me to suspect if VS intercepts the connection. Is this your case? Debugging in VS?

Comment: Thank you very much for reminding me. I was in VS mode. I should start uwp first, then manually start WinForm.

Comment: By design, and I also verify this in my test, the UWP app that exposes the service (the service provider) does not have to be running when the connection is attempted. It will be triggered when request is coming.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for your help